# WordPress -Why are shortcodes being ignored in my custom post type?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using Visual Composer which works great on my posts and pages, however, when I view a custom post type that I created using Visual Composer, all of the shortcodes are ignored so the page looks something like the following...

> [vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]I am a text box.[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row]

My cpt template uses the wordpress loop `<?php the_content(); ?>` and shotcodes are ignored. My other page templates also use `<?php the_content(); ?>` but all the Visual Composer shortcodes work perfectly.

I tried replacing my cpt template with my default page template and the shortcodes were still ignored so I don't think it's a template issue because I concluded that using the default page template for a page post works perfectly but using the same template for a cpt post does not work and ignores the shorcodes.

I don't know what is causing this.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors in your console?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you missed the wp_head(); at the header or wp_footer at the footer

Comment: They are not missing, otherwise my default page template wouldn't work at all. Both header and footer loops are in the templates.